# AJAX call then page redirect

Tags: ajax

I can call an AJAX request when a form submit button is clicked, but if the page reloads/redirects due to the form submission, will the AJAX request still complete? I'm asking this so I could do something like upload a file via AJAX as the form is submitted.

I'm pretty sure I can't get the output of the AJAX call, but could I be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but there's no guarantee that the request would have completed by the time you leave the page. If you're submitting a form via AJAX and also want to submit a file, you might consider placing the file upload in a completely separate form tag, then trigger the form submission after the AJAX call is successful. For example:

```
<!-- First form with your data -->
<form action="/your/url/here" method="post" id="form1">
   <input type="text" name="title" />
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<!-- Second form with your file -->
<form action="/uploadfile" method="post" id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="fileupload" />
</form>
```

Then in Javascript (using jQuery example for brevity, note I haven't tested this code at all):

```
$('#form1').bind('submit', function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      type: 'post',
      success: function() {
        $('#form2').submit();
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Matt! I was looking to see if the request would continue server side once the rest of the page has been submitted client side.